# Display UIprogressiveView for uploading videos to server in iphone

Tags: iphone, video, uiimagepickercontroller, asihttprequest

I am obtaining a recorded video using UIImagePickerController, i got the URL and converted it to data, now I want to upload the video to a server,

As video files take more time to upload, I want to show UIProgressiveView how much content is uploaded, how to achieve this functionality.

I am using ASIFormDataRequest for uploading data to the server.

Please help me in it..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your `UIProgressView` as ASIHTTPRequest's progress delegate:

```
[request setDownloadProgressDelegate:myProgressView]
```

ASIHTTPRequest will call `setProgress:` periodically on it.

Edit: When uploading, use this instead:

```
[request setUploadProgressDelegate:myProgressView]
```

Comment: hi.., thank you.., as for uploading I used [request setUploadDelegateProgressDelegate:progressView];